# What is the darkling?

Tags: the-darkness-2

Throughout the game, the darkling helps you a lot. Near the end, you learn that he's at the mercy of the darkness and that it can kill it, it even fears it.

What side is the darkling on? Why does he help you? Is he somehow part of the darkness?

Comment: I suspect the answer might container a lot of spoilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Darkling (the demon-looking thing that refers to you only as "Monkey" and speaks with a British accent) is on your side, but mainly because you are possessed by the Darkness and your death means his death.

> This is why the Darkling may die if exposed to light until you defeat the Darkness inside your mind and save Jenny's soul, trapping you within the Darkness's cage forever.